# not(:last-child)

Tags: css

```css
ul{
  display:flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: green;
  
  li{
    margin-left: 10px;
    
    a{
      text-decoration: none;
      color: inherit;
      &:not(:last-child)&:after{  
        content:"~";
        display:inline-block;
        
      }     
      
      
    }
     
    
  }
  
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">lastchild</a></li>
</ul>
```

Как правильно записать что у последнего :after не было "~";

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ваш пример нерабочий, потому что так задать стили можно только используя less.js. Если брать обычный css то это можно написать так.

```css
ul{
  display:flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: green;
}

ul > li {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

ul > li > a{
      text-decoration: none;
      color: inherit;
}
  
ul > li:not(:last-child) > a:after{  
        content:"~";
        display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/3.0.0/less.min.js" ></script>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">lastchild</a></li>
</ul>
```

Или можно задать стиль последнему элементу и удалить его содержимое.

```css
ul{
  display:flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: green;
}

ul > li {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

ul > li > a{
      text-decoration: none;
      color: inherit;
}
  
ul > li > a:after{  
        content:"~";
        display:inline-block;
}

ul > li:last-child > a:after{  
        content:"";
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/3.0.0/less.min.js" ></script>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">lastchild</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно исключить последний элемент списка (li):

```
li {
 &:not(:last-child) {
  a::after {

  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li:not(:last-child) a:after {
  content: "~";
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">lastchild</a></li>
</ul>
```